# Extract the day of fortnight from Date objects?

Tags: r, date

In my analysis, I have to extract the day of a week and the day number of each fortnight from Date objects. I want the result to look like below

```
Date                 weekday         fortnightly    
2010-05-01           Saturday            1 
2010-05-02           Sunday              2
.
.
2010-05-14           Friday              14 
2010-05-15           Saturday            1
2010-05-16           Sunday              2
.
.
2010-05-28           Friday              14  
2010-05-29           Saturday            1
2010-05-30           Sunday              2
2010-05-31           Monday              3  
2010-06-1            Tuesday             4
2010-06-2            Wednesday           5
```

I extracted the weekday as below

```
df$weekday <- weekdays(as.Date(df$Date))
```

However, I don't know which function I can use to extract the day number for each fortnight.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

Taking @akrun's data as reference

```
v1 <- seq(as.Date('2010-05-01'), length.out=60, by = '1 day')
c(rep(seq(1, 14, 1), floor(length(v1)/14)), 1:(length(v1)%%14))

# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14  1  2  3  4
# [33]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14  1  2  3  4
```

Repeating a sequence of numbers from 1 to 14 for `length(v1)/14` times and then appending the remaining numbers.

So if in your case it's a data frame then you can try,

```
c(rep(seq(1, 14, 1), floor(nrow(df)/14)), 1:(nrow(df)%%14))
```

which would again generate the same sequence.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried your code and I got this error
Error in rep(seq(1, 14, 1), floor(nrow(df$Date)/14)) : 
  invalid 'times' argument

Comment: @aelwan Try with `nrow(df)` and not `nrow(df$Date)`

Answer (score 2):

We can try

```
(seq_along(v1)-1)%%14 + 1L
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
#[26] 12 13 14  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
#[51]  9 10 11 12 13 14  1  2  3  4
```

#### data

```
v1 <- seq(as.Date('2010-05-01'), length.out=60, by = '1 day')
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked well till the end of first month (May) in the dataset. However, at the start of the new month (2010-06-01), it started again as 1 which shouldn't be the case. It should be 14 each two weeks irrespective of the month. Your answer starts as 1 with the first day of each new month. Thanks again.

Comment: Your updated answer is exactly what I wanted. Thanks again.